# Get the list of names via Get Metadata activity

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

Below is the output of Get Metadata activity which contains name and type values for child items:

[image]

Is it possible to just get the name values and stored within an array variable without using any iteration.

Output = [csv1.csv,csv2.csv,csv3.csv,csv4.csv]

This was achieved via Foreach and append variable, we don't want to use iterations.

Answer (score 1):

**APPROACH 1 :**

Using for each would be easier to complete the job. However, you can use string manipulation in the following way to get the desired result.

- Store the output of get metadata child items in a variable as a string:

```
@string(activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems)
```

[image]

- Now replace all the unnecessary data with empty string `''` using the following dynamic content:

```
@replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(variables('tp'),'[{',''),'}]',''),'{',''),'}',''),'"type":"File"',''),'"',''),'name:',''),',,',',')
```

[image]

- Now, ignore the last comma and split the above string with `,` as delimiter.

```
@split(substring(variables('ans'),0,sub(length(variables('ans')),1)),',')
```

[image]

**APPROACH 2 :**

Let's say your source has a combination of folders and files, and you want only the names of objects whose type is File in an array, then you can use the following approach. Here there is no need of for each, but you will have to use copy data and dataflows.

- Create a copy data activity with a sample file with data like below:

[image]

- Now create an additional column `my_json` with value as the following dynamic content:

```
@replace(string(activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems),'"',pipeline().parameters.single_quote)
```

- The following is the sink dataset configuration that I have taken:

[image]

- In the mapping, just select this newly created column and remove the rest (demo) column.

[image]

- Once this copy data executes, the file generated will be as shown below:

[image]

- In dataflow, with the above file as source with settings as shown in the below image:

[image]

- The data would be read as shown below:

[image]

- Now, use aggregate transformation to group by the type column and collect() on `name` column.

[image]

- The result would be as shown below:

[image]

- Now, use conditional split to separate the file type data and folder type data with the condition `type == 'File'`

[image]

- Now write the fileType data to sink cache. The data would look like this:

[image]

- Back in the pipeline, use the following dynamic content to get the required array:

```
@activity('Data flow1').output.runStatus.output.sink1.value[0].array_of_types
```

[image]

Pipeline JSON for reference:

```
{
    "name": "pipeline3",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Get Metadata1",
                "type": "GetMetadata",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "source1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "fieldList": [
                        "childItems"
                    ],
                    "storeSettings": {
                        "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                        "recursive": true,
                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                    },
                    "formatSettings": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Copy data1",
                "type": "Copy",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Get Metadata1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                        "additionalColumns": [
                            {
                                "name": "my_json",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@replace(string(activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems),'\"',pipeline().parameters.single_quote)",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                            "recursive": true,
                            "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                        },
                        "formatSettings": {
                            "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                        }
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextSink",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobFSWriteSettings"
                        },
                        "formatSettings": {
                            "type": "DelimitedTextWriteSettings",
                            "quoteAllText": true,
                            "fileExtension": ".txt"
                        }
                    },
                    "enableStaging": false,
                    "translator": {
                        "type": "TabularTranslator",
                        "mappings": [
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "name": "my_json",
                                    "type": "String"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "type": "String",
                                    "physicalType": "String",
                                    "ordinal": 1
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "typeConversion": true,
                        "typeConversionSettings": {
                            "allowDataTruncation": true,
                            "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
                        }
                    }
                },
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "csv1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ],
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "sink1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Data flow1",
                "type": "ExecuteDataFlow",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Copy data1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "dataflow": {
                        "referenceName": "dataflow2",
                        "type": "DataFlowReference"
                    },
                    "compute": {
                        "coreCount": 8,
                        "computeType": "General"
                    },
                    "traceLevel": "None"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Set variable2",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Data flow1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "req",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@activity('Data flow1').output.runStatus.output.sink1.value[0].array_of_types",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "parameters": {
            "single_quote": {
                "type": "string",
                "defaultValue": "'"
            }
        },
        "variables": {
            "req": {
                "type": "Array"
            },
            "tp": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "ans": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "req_array": {
                "type": "Array"
            }
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "lastPublishTime": "2023-02-03T06:09:07Z"
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines"
}
```

Dataflow JSON for reference:

```
{
    "name": "dataflow2",
    "properties": {
        "type": "MappingDataFlow",
        "typeProperties": {
            "sources": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "Json3",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "source1"
                }
            ],
            "sinks": [
                {
                    "name": "sink1"
                }
            ],
            "transformations": [
                {
                    "name": "aggregate1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "split1"
                }
            ],
            "scriptLines": [
                "source(output(",
                "          name as string,",
                "          type as string",
                "     ),",
                "     allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     ignoreNoFilesFound: false,",
                "     documentForm: 'arrayOfDocuments',",
                "     singleQuoted: true) ~> source1",
                "source1 aggregate(groupBy(type),",
                "     array_of_types = collect(name)) ~> aggregate1",
                "aggregate1 split(type == 'File',",
                "     disjoint: false) ~> split1@(fileType, folderType)",
                "split1@fileType sink(validateSchema: false,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true,",
                "     store: 'cache',",
                "     format: 'inline',",
                "     output: true,",
                "     saveOrder: 1) ~> sink1"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```